# How to ignore installed flake8 plugin easily for one time?

Tags: flake8

I have `flake8-docstrings` plugin installed and some others. But for some runs I want to ignore all the warnings of this plugin in some easy way: without creating a config file and without making a list of it's warning codes manually.

Is there any solution like:

```
flake8 . --ignore=Dxxx
```

or

```
flake8 . --disable-plugin=docstrings
```

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're almost there

```
flake8 --extend-ignore=D .
```

Will ignore all violations reported that start with `D` and `flake8-docstrings` is the only plugin that reports codes starting with `D`.

If you have suggestions on how to improve [this section](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html?highlight=ignore#cmdoption-flake8-extend-ignore) of documentation that describes how to do it, please open an issue.